# Prevent non-administrator accounts from seeing time machine drive

Tags: time-machine, permission, user-account

I have added a standard, non administrator account to my Mac running Ventura 13.2

The new account can read files from an attached drive being used as a Time Machine and I would like to prevent this.

It looks like I have the capability to change permissions on folders within the backup but I would like to make all current and future backups inaccessible to the non-admin account. Only the admin account should be able to read the backup files.

Is this possible?

Comment: Each user should be able to see the same files they can access directly on the Mac, from their own account. Is this not sufficient? I think it would be very unwise to try changing permissions inside a Time Machine drive.

Comment: @Tetsujin That doesn't seem to be the case? I am able to see all the files of the administrator account in the backups from the non-administrator account.

Comment: Should be like this if you look into another account - https://i.stack.imgur.com/t4QoB.jpg

Comment: @Tetsujin you are correct. The permissions are wrong on some of my folders. I am surprised that the default permissions when running `mkdir` in the administrator account appears to enable read access for all users. Going to ask a separate question about fixing this.

Comment: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/456647/fix-permissions-on-used-and-unused-time-machine-backups

Comment: I think removing the user from the "staff" group might fix it but the commands I have run to do that don't seem to work.

Comment: Beyond my pay-grade really, but I'm not sure how you'd do that retrospectively.